# Video library for android device

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am trying to build an application with custom video player. I have to add customization on the play pause button, seekbar etc.

Primarily i am targeting to view only youtube videos but might be will support other sources in future updates.

I have searched around for the same on the internet and found several blogs which points to youtube api library.

Is there any other way to make my own custom library where i can add my own add on [UI factors]. Please help me by giving me the right sources to start doing it.

Thanks in advance.